# make a Mastodon local development environment, problem with manifest.json and yarn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yarnpkg, webpacker

i want to make a dev environment to make stuff for my Mastodon version. But i cannot find a way to build the react app's manifest.json
when i run "foreman start", the services run fine, but the frontend, http://localhost:3000 prompts an error message about the build. The manifest json has a problem, it is missing a "common" part, as webpacker says. it is full of a lot of js files references though.

```
Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError: Webpacker can't find common in XXX/manifest.json
```

i tried reinstalling gems, wiping yarn cache, removing node_modules, changing ruby version with RVM. nothing beats that.

here is my repo, on the branch feature-im
https://framagit.org/tykayn/mastodon/tree/feature-im
but the same happens on master, which i merge regularly with the tootsuite/mastodon version from github.
https://framagit.org/tykayn/mastodon

system info:

```
============
rails version : Rails 5.2.3
ruby version : ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-linux]
ruby env : development
rvm version :rvm 1.29.9 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]
node version : v12.11.0
node env : 
yarn version : 1.17.3
system version : Linux fatland 5.0.0-37-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 00:14:01 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
============
```

here is the complete output of my failing assets:precompile logs; it is where the build fails to join the manifest.json "common" part . pastebin.com/QMZ1yCUe

Comment: How are you starting foreman locally? Just for a sanity check, I believe you want to specify the `Procile.dev` config file: https://framagit.org/tykayn/mastodon/blob/master/Procfile.dev

Comment: Otherwise, if you prefer to run without the dev-server, check to be sure there's not already something listening on port 3035 since Rails won't shell out to compile if it thinks the dev-server is running. https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/96af013eed295576ac246f46dee1d01d67888801/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb#L54

Comment: i do `foreman start` and it takes correctly the Procfile.dev, not the other one, i tested it with the RUBY_ENV set to production. specifiying no RUBY_ENV runs the development one.

Comment: @rossta i saw there is nothing running on the port 3035 with `netstat -pna |grep 3035`

Comment: the problem here is clearly a react app build problem, the manifest seems to be missing something, but i have no idea how to add it at build time

Comment: What output do you get when you run ./bin/webpack?

Comment: more insight for @rossta , here is the complete output of my failing assets:precompile logs; it is where the build fails to join the manifest.json "common" part .

https://pastebin.com/QMZ1yCUe

Comment: thanks—is there no helpful output if you run straight: `./bin/webpack`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204064/discussion-between-ty-kayn-and-rossta).

Comment: webpack builds succefully if i run it. but the ./bin/webpack-dev-server does not